# Flutter - Build Failed With An Exception. How to upgrade dependencies?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

**This is the what I am getting in Android Studio**

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1159
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I tried using flutter pub upgrade --major-versions but the issue has not been resolved.
This is what it showed after using flutter pub upgrade --major-versions

```
Resolving dependencies...
  async 2.9.0 (2.10.0 available)
  boolean_selector 2.1.0 (2.1.1 available)
  characters 1.2.1
  clock 1.1.1
  collection 1.16.0 (1.17.0 available)
  cupertino_icons 1.0.5
  fake_async 1.3.1
  flutter 0.0.0 from sdk flutter
  flutter_test 0.0.0 from sdk flutter
  matcher 0.12.12 (0.12.14 available)
  material_color_utilities 0.1.5 (0.2.0 available)
  meta 1.8.0
  path 1.8.2 (1.8.3 available)
  sky_engine 0.0.99 from sdk flutter
  source_span 1.9.0 (1.9.1 available)
  stack_trace 1.10.0 (1.11.0 available)
  stream_channel 2.1.0 (2.1.1 available)
  string_scanner 1.1.1 (1.2.0 available)
  term_glyph 1.2.1
  test_api 0.4.12 (0.4.17 available)
  vector_math 2.1.2 (2.1.4 available)
No dependencies changed.
12 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints.
Try `flutter pub outdated` for more information.
```

Upon using flutter pub outdated this is what I got

[*] indicates versions that are not the latest available.

Package Name              Current   Upgradable  Resolvable  Latest

direct dependencies: all up-to-date.

transitive dependencies:
collection                *1.16.0   *1.16.0     *1.16.0     1.17.0
material_color_utilities  *0.1.5    *0.1.5      *0.1.5      0.2.0
vector_math               *2.1.2    *2.1.2      *2.1.2      2.1.4

transitive dev_dependencies:
async                     *2.9.0    *2.9.0      *2.9.0      2.10.0
boolean_selector          *2.1.0    *2.1.0      *2.1.0      2.1.1
matcher                   *0.12.12  *0.12.12    *0.12.12    0.12.14
path                      *1.8.2    *1.8.2      *1.8.2      1.8.3
source_span               *1.9.0    *1.9.0      *1.9.0      1.9.1
stack_trace               *1.10.0   *1.10.0     *1.10.0     1.11.0
stream_channel            *2.1.0    *2.1.0      *2.1.0      2.1.1
string_scanner            *1.1.1    *1.1.1      *1.1.1      1.2.0
test_api                  *0.4.12   *0.4.12     *0.4.12     0.4.17
all dependencies are up-to-date.

Can someone please tell me how to solve this issue? I cannot figure out what needs to be done here.
I keep getting the same error code.
How to update these dependencies to the newer version? I don't know how to do it.

Comment: What is the output of `flutter pub get`?

Comment: Actually I tried running the project with a physical device and the issue got resolved. I will run again with a virtual device in android studio to see if the issue persists.